# What will be the output of given linux code?

Tags: linux

What will be the last line of the output when running the following script? Assume that the user will enter the name 'luk' and the email 'luk@gmail.com'?

```
# bin/bash

echo "Please enter your name"

read

echo "Please enter your Email"

read

echo 

"$REPLY"
```

a) lukluk@gmail.cpm

b)luk

c)luk@gmail.com

4)no output

5)script will throw an error

Comment: Hello Utkarsh. Have you tried running the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# bin/bash

echo "Please enter your name"    
read    
echo "Please enter your Email"    
read    
echo
"$REPLY"
```

It will throw an  error.